# python-dev: how to change library architecture

Tags: python, c, python-2.7

I am trying to use the python-dev api but I am running into a few issues.

This is the code I am trying to compile

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <Python.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);  /* optional but recommended */
  Py_Initialize();
  PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                     "print 'Today is',ctime(time())\n");
  Py_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

With

```
gcc -c test.c `python-config --cflags`
```

First of, I have python 2.7.8 installed in my (OSX 10.9) computer.

When I run `python-config --cflags` I get this output:

```
-I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch ppc -arch i386 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3
```

So for some reason, even though I have python 2.7.8, python-dev api is python 2.6. I tried reinstalling python but that did me no good.

Secondly, for some reason python is trying to use powerpc and i386 architecture with the `-arch ppc -arc i386`, but that I fixed with `python-config --cflags | sed -e 's/-arch\ .*\ //g`.

But even though I am successfully compiling my code, the linker is still getting weird architecture code from python-dev:

```
gcc test.o -o test `python-config --ldlags`

ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/config/libpython2.6.dylib, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/config/libpython2.6.dylib (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_PyRun_SimpleStringFlags", referenced from:
      _main in test.o
  "_Py_Finalize", referenced from:
      _main in test.o
  "_Py_Initialize", referenced from:
      _main in test.o
  "_Py_SetProgramName", referenced from:
      _main in test.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

In the [Homebrew github page](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/25873) I found this:

> ld: warning: ignoring file
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/config/libpython2.6.dylib,
>   missing required architecture x86_64 in file
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/config/libpython2.6.dylib
>   (2 slices) It looks like you have a 32-bit version of Python installed
>   - probably PowerPC/i386. Since you have a 64-bit computer, you need your default Python to have a 64-bit component too.

But they never explained how to do that.

How can I get the API to work?

**UPDATE** - Compiling with cflags gets rid of the ignored files but still gives me undefined symbols:

```
gcc test.o -o test `python-config --cflags --ldflags | sed -e 's/-arch\ .*\ //g' | sed -e 's/Versions\/2\.6/Versions\/Current/g'`
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_PyRun_SimpleStringFlags", referenced from:
      _main in test.o
  "_Py_Finalize", referenced from:
      _main in test.o
  "_Py_Initialize", referenced from:
      _main in test.o
  "_Py_SetProgramName", referenced from:
      _main in test.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**UPDATE** - The problem is that python is installed in `/usr/local/Cellar/Frameworks` in my machine but for some reason python-config still thinks it's in `/Library/Frameworks`.
So now the real question is: How do I change the path for python-config?
My PYTHONPATH env variable is correct, so I have no clue as to why it was not changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only passing the compiler flags. Pass linker flags as well. Otherwise, libraries symbols will not be linked:

```
gcc -c test.c `python-config --cflags --ldflags`
```

To solve the undefined symbols problem, python-config could be using the wrong interpreter. Open python-config (it is a regular python file) at `which python-config` and check the first line for something like this `#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6`
If it does not point to the right interpreter, change it to the correct path.

Comment: No more ignored files, but still getting missing symbol errors

Comment: I don't know if python-dev was installed properly. You shouldn't need to do the `sed` replacements. If `python-config` gives wrong architectures, then it's mostly an install issue. Can you install same version of python-dev as python?

Comment: Found the problem. python-config is set to `/Library/....` instead of `/usr/local/Cellar/....` which is where python is actually installed. How do I change that?